# retrieving type returned by function using "typeof" operator in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, typeof

We can get the type returned by function in gcc using the typeof operator as follows:

```
typeof(container.begin()) i;
```

Is it possible to do something similar for functions taking some arguments, but not giving them? E.g. when we have function:

```
MyType foo(int, char, bool, int);
```

I want to retrieve this "MyType" (probably using typeof operator) assuming I know only the name of function ("foo") and have no knowledge about arguments it takes. Is it possible?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. Besides, what if "foo" has overloads that return different types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ the return value's type is not part of the method signature.  Even if there is a way to get the return type of a method, you would have to deal with the possibility of getting multiple methods back and not knowing which one went with the return type you want.

Comment: Though it's not part of the signature, it _is_ part of the type.  You cannot assign an `int (*)( void )` to a `float (*)(void)`, for instance.

Answer (score 6):

`typeof` is a non-standard extension, so don't use it if you want your code to be portable.

Its syntax is `typeof(expression)`, so you need to give it an expression calling the function (whose type is therefore `MyType`), like this:

```
typeof(foo(int(),char(),bool(),int()))
```

Comment: +1. It might be worth pointing out that this expression is a so-called "unevaluated context" just like the expressions for sizeof are not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

C++0x is going to introduce a [Type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference) using the `decltype` and `auto` keywords.
In C++ you can use `typeof` (as suggested by Mike Seymour) or the SFINAE principle.